# A lightweight javascript library for interactive graph plotting?

Tags: javascript, graph

I am interested in knowing the most lightweight javascript library for plotting interactive graphs. The data that I have is mostly scientific data related to ocean research.

I know a few of the jquery library namely Highcharts, and JS charts. But what I am looking for is most lightweight library. The graph does not need to feed live data but it must be interactive.

Comment: Did you try http://jpgraph.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely recommend [D3.js](http://d3js.org/).

There are some extremely well made data driven documents and examples using it. Many presentations from the recent [VizSec](http://www.vizsec.org/) conference made use of it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Some of my co-workers have used Flot JQuery plugin. Check that out. http://www.flotcharts.org/