# Javascript plot package to move points/lines

Tags: javascript, plot

I am looking for an interactive plot Javascript library for an educational book. I want the user to be able to do things like move a line up or down and see the resulting intersection point or region.

There have been many questions about interactive plots in javascript:

- [A lightweight javascript library for interactive graph plotting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483180/a-lightweight-javascript-library-for-interactive-graph-plotting)
- [Interactive javascript chart without jQuery and with cursor plotting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24214409/interactive-javascript-chart-without-jquery-and-with-cursor-plotting)

None seem interactive in the sense I am looking for AFAIK. (They seem to be interactive in the sense that they show balloon text and can react to simple events like clicking in points.)

**[Please see here](https://rawgit.com/rpmcruz/price-theory/master/graph/graph.html)** an example of something I want my plot to support.

Does a plotting package that allows this kind of interactiveness exist or should I implement my own? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [Flot](https://github.com/flot/flot) plus the [Flot cursors plugin](https://github.com/cipix2000/flot-cursors-plugin)

This demo seems to look alike the one you made https://rawgit.com/cipix2000/flot-cursors-plugin/master/example.html - just turn of the Dynamic chart data, then you can drag the line

Or maybe make your own flot plugin.

Comment: Flot seems to allow the kind of things I have in mind. It does seem a bit cumbersome. The plugin alone is almost a thousand lines, and does not fill areas which I also need. But I will take a closer look at Flot, thanks!

Comment: I have decided to hack something together with D3.js. I do appreciate your package suggestion. From all I have seen, it seems the most flexible plotting package.

Comment: Okay, great that you found a solution, but i dont think that there are anything out there that fulfil your needs 100%, but yes Flot is very flexible.